# overflow:scroll in css

Tags: css, hover, mouseover

I have an element that i've styled with "overflow:scroll", but it looks bad because the scroll bar clutters up the page. Is there any way to make the scroll bar only show when someone mouses over the element?

Answer (score 3):

Yep!

Add a class to the area where you want to scroll, like:

```
<div class="over">Content to scroll</div>
```

Your CSS will look like this:
    `.over { overflow:hidden }`
    `.over:hover { overflow-y:scroll }`

[Here's a link to an example](http://jsfiddle.net/dYrBK/1/).

Answer (score 2):

```
#element_id {
    overflow: hidden;
}

#element_id:hover {
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

works if you don't care about ie6 users

Comment: You might have to define the height/width of `#element_id` too.

Answer (score 0):

```
#element { overflow: hidden; }
#element:hover { overflow: scroll; }
```

Though `:hover` doesn't work in IE 6 so you'll want to keep that in mind.

If you need to support IE 6, you'll need to do this sort of thing with JavaScript and classes on the element.

Comment: Yup, that would work. There are a lot of others as well. Good to have the link on the post though :)

Answer (score 0):

If the :hover pseudo class worked consistently across all browsers, you could do:

```
.my_thing
{
    overflow: visible;
}

.my_thing:hover
{
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Your best best is to set the class on hover via JavaScript.